# PHP Foreach loop only displaying last result

Tags: php

I am having a bit of trouble with some code where in an array I have a list of 2 and the function is only displaying the last in the list.

Here is the code:

```
<?php


  function getKeywordPosition($theurl,$thekeywords) {

    $theurl = $theurl;
    $thekeywords = $thekeywords;

    $found = false;
    $x = 0;

    for($x; $x < 64 && $found == false;)
{
    $url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
    . "q=".stripslashes(str_replace(' ', '%20', $thekeywords)).'&start='.$x;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.boo.com');
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode($body);

    $x4 = $x + 4;
    $old_x = $x;

    for($x; $x < $x4 && $found == false; $x = $x + 1)
        {

            if (strpos($json->responseData->results[$x-$old_x]->unescapedUrl, strtolower($theurl)) !== false) 
            {
                $found = true;
            }

        }

        // now have some fun with the results...
    }

    if($found)
    {
        echo '<strong>'.$theurl.'</strong> is located as the <strong>'.$x.'</strong> result when searching for <strong>'.stripslashes($thekeywords).'</strong>';
        echo '<br>';
    }

  }


    $list = array('php.com'=>'php', 'php.com'=>'php');

    foreach($list as $key => $value){

        getKeywordPosition($key,$value);

    }



?>
```

Why is this not working properly?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of `$x` as it's iterating through? My guess is that it's your nested loop that's bugging it up.

Comment: What is this meant to express: `$list = array('php.com'=>'php', 'php.com'=>'php');`? The two keys are identical, so you end up with only a single element. Certainly a foreach loop based on that array will only give single iteration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless this is a badly contrived example, then th issue is you have duplicate keys in your array:

```
$list = array('php.com'=>'php', 'php.com'=>'php');
```

This array has a single entry

You coud refactor like so:

```
$list = array(

    array('url'=>'php.net', 'keyword'=>'php'),
    array('url'=>'php.net', 'keyword'=>'arrays'),
    array('url'=>'php.net', 'keyword'=>'anotherkeyword')
    );


foreach($list as $entry){

    getKeywordPosition($entry['url'], $entry['keyword']);

}
```

Comment: If I was to do this: $list = array('php.com'=>'php', 'php.com'=>'php code'); ...it will just display the last one ... keywords are different here and if I did this: $list = array('php.net'=>'php', 'php.com'=>'php code'); which are totally different, I still get the last result only, so it has to be something else

Comment: Are you sure? So if you remove the foreach loop and add two function calls: getKeywordPosition('php.net','php'); getKeywordPosition('php.com','php code'); then do you only get one or both results?

Comment: If I do this: getKeywordPosition('php.net','php'); getKeywordPosition('php.net','php.net'); I get 2 results

Comment: and if I use this: $list = array('php.net'=>'php', 'php.net'=>'php.net');

 foreach($list as $key => $value){

  getKeywordPosition($key,$value);

 } I just get the last one

Comment: Right, thats consistent with my point about array indexes. They must always be unique, so the example in your last comment will fail. so $list = array('php.net'=>'php', 'cat.com'=>'cat'); should get two results as well

Comment: However, you should refactor this to avoid the problem. I will edit my answer with a solution

Comment: Oh I see your point now. I cannot take off the downvote unless you edit your answer for some reason :o/  Do you have any idea of what I could do to sort this? I need the url to have more that one same entry though :o/